# Create a 3D Bar Chart in ggplot

Tags: python, charts

I am new to Python and am trying to create a 3D Bar Chart in ggplot with the Date on the X-Axis, quarter on the y-axis, and value on the z-axis.

```
Index Date    Value   quarter
0   03/2001     946     1
1   06/2001     892     2
2   09/2001     866     3
3   12/2001     924     4
4   03/2002     917     1
```

I have tried the following code:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style

style.use('ggplot')

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

fig=plt.figure()
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
x3=df['Date']
y3=df['quarter']

dx=np.ones(10)
dy=np.ones(10)
dz=df['Value']

ax1.bar3d(x3,y3,z3,dx,dy,dz)

ax1.set_xlabel('Date')
ax2.set_xlabel('Quarter')
ax3.set_xlabel('Home Sales')

ax1.set_title('Home Sales')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What is the issue with this code? The code also doesn't really use ggplot library.

Comment: I keep getting ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape but I have looked at the dataframe and everything is the same length

Comment: What is `z3` here? Where is it defined?